# Versioning APIs during internal development

Tags: api, maven, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

In our team we have a number of APIs specified using the Open API Specification (formerly Swagger). We use Maven and OpenAPI Generator to generate code, build and publish the artifact to our local nexus. We build our code on TeamCity. The artifact is given the version that is specified in the pom.xml file of Maven.

During development we only use snapshot versions, that is versions which can be overwritten and will be cleaned up. This is opposite to release versions, that cannot be overwritten and needs administrative privileges to clean up. The reason for this is, that a developer usually changes a little bit at the time, which is much more convenient with snapshot versions. This also makes cleaning up outdated unreleased artifacts much easier.

Our problem is, that from time to time a developer makes API changes but forgets to set a new version. This works fine locally, but when the code is build on TeamCity the changed API overwrites the artifact of an older version. A developer not working on this branch will then experience a compile error, because the code does not match the API artifact being used.

What does others do? Is there a best practice? Preferably with standard tools. We have tried many things and nothing works well. At the same time this issue is so basic that someone must have a good solution - or at least experience enough to point to the least bad solution.

Comment: This means: `but forgets to set a new version. `... updating the versions is done manually? Why not using the release mechanism to automatically update the version...?

Comment: At what point should the release mechanism be used? Manually by the developer or should it be run by the build server (at every build)?

Comment: Depends what you like to achieve that every change in master/main will produce a new release or maybe not ...

Comment: My main question is: How does other teams handle versioning of their APIs during development. Especially if someone have found a solution that causes no versioning conflicts.
The solution may be that every build on master/main/develop causes a release in Maven that we will have to clean up later. Then we use the release feature for a "team release" and not a public release.
But I would really like to hear other teams experiences before trying more approaches than we have already tried.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: `Especially if someone have found a solution that causes no versioning conflicts.` ?

Comment: By that statement I mean: I am especially looking for a solution that can guarantee that if a developer makes API changes and only makes sure the code on the developers branch works (i.e. no manual change of a version), then no other developers will be affected when the code is delivered and build on the build server.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand a thing but what should that mean: `then no other developers will be affected when the code is delivered and build on the build server.`? Do you have automated tests. This sounds like merging is a problem? But what exactly?